# Dismiss Popover ViewController from Tableviewcell in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipopovercontroller

In my iOS 8 app I've got a custom ViewController which I present as Popover. This ViewController has a delegate, which get, and send to parent ViewController, the clicked index in popup. The problem is that I can't dismiss this Popover after selectRow.

Here's the code:

This is the method which I call when I want to show my Popup.

```
 @IBAction func registerButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    popup = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopupViewController") as? PopupViewController
    popup!.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popup!.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 120)
    let popoverMenuViewController = popup!.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Up
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: sender.frame.size.width/2,
        y: sender.frame.size.height/2,
        width: 1,
        height: 1)
    popup!.delegate = self

    presentViewController(
        popup!,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)

}
```

Here's PopupViewController code:

```
protocol PopupViewControllerDelegate
{
    func rowClickedAtIndex(var index : Int)
}

class PopupViewController: MainViewController {

    var delegate : PopupViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension PopupViewController:UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell:PopupTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PopupTableViewCell") as? PopupTableViewCell

        if cell == nil {
            cell = PopupTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "PopupTableViewCell")
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (self.delegate != nil)
        {
            self.delegate!.rowClickedAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 2
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I solved by myself:

I checked that the problem wasn't that the popover wasn't dismissed, but it was dismissed but after different seconds.

So I put my dismiss call in the main thread and it worked perfectly. Here's the code:

```
extension WelcomeViewController: PopupViewControllerDelegate {
    func rowClickedAtIndex(index: Int) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            println(index)
        })
    }
}
```

I want to thank you Frankie, who helped me in finding the solution, removing what shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Move your `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` call into the delegate at the end of the `clickedRowAtIndex` method.  In other words, the presenting view controller should call the dismissing, not the presented view controller.

Try this:

```
extension WelcomeViewController: PopupViewControllerDelegate { 
    func rowClickedAtIndex(index: Int) {      
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)   
        println(index) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I've tried here:


extension WelcomeViewController: PopupViewControllerDelegate {
    func rowClickedAtIndex(index: Int) {
        popup?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        println(index)
    }
}
But it doesn't work..It passes in this method because it prints the index, but it doesn't dismiss it.

Comment: That looks like `popup` is still trying to perform the call.  `WelcomeViewController` needs to perform it.   `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Comment: What should I do in your opinion?

Comment: It's really strange: I noticed that if I tap the row immediately later that it's presented, it works correctly. If I wait a second or more, I have to tap the row twice to dismiss it.

Comment: Does `rowClickedAtIndex` get called just once or twice when you have to tap the row twice?

Comment: The method is called twice, in fact my println is printed twice on my console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77932/discussion-between-bellots-and-frankie).